# Using Count function in Excel with conditional color formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need some Excel help.

I have a massive spreadsheet of of employee names. The spreadsheet lists the last names of every employee in Column A. I use the spreadsheet at the end of every year to award bonuses, and beside each name in other columns I make notes about annual performance. There are several hundred names on the spreadsheet.

I like to keep track of every person who quits the company during the year.

So, when someone retires or leaves, I choose to color fill with red the box where the last name is. See the attached: [image: Red Box example]

At the top of the spreadsheet, in a separate cell, I'm trying to keep track of how many people have left the company over the previous year - i.e., how many people have their last name cells filled in with red.

Is there a way to automatically count how many cells in a particular column have been filled with red?

I have researched online about conditional formatting, but I haven't found an answer to this particular problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it via formula. It should be doable with VBA; you are probably looking for a user defined function.

Comment: This looks useful https://professor-excel.com/how-to-return-the-background-color-code-from-excel-cell/

Comment: Now, for the VBA solution the main catch is changing the cell's color does not trigger an event. Therefore your user defined function won't update itself when you just change the colors. You might use a subroutine that will need you to do something (like click a button or select a specific cell) in order to have the result returned. You could also use the first workaround of Tom Sharpe's link, but it would take more clicks than a VBA solution. In the end you could also change the way you mark the gone employee, say adding a column dedicated to the task and then use COUNT or COUNTIF.

Comment: I would suggest to **add a new column "LeaveDate"**. Then you can use conditional formatting to e.g. make the name grey (which makes more sense to me than to highlight those persons) and you can count the "LeaveDates" for your statistic and you can filter for those persons who are still part of your company.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but to be honest, for the long run I believe that Ike's comment contains the best solution.

Comment: Use Conditional Color Formatting to reference for counting is really not recommended, i would always follow the way @Ike ma'am has suggested. Using color as a reference for counting only makes life more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using get.cell, this is an Excel 4 (Macro) function and it will only work on named ranges. The workbook will have to become a macro enabled workbook.

You will need to add a new column to the left of the column that contains the coloured cells, in this instance we will have the formula in Column A and the coloured cells in Column B.

Change any cell references below to match your workbook structure.

1. Select Cell A1
2. On the **Formulas** tab in the ribbon, click on **Name Manager**
3. In the Name Manager click **New...**
4. Give the list a New Name: **ColouredCell**
5. Refers to, enter the formula: `=GET.CELL(63,!B1)`
6. Click **OK** then **Close** Name Manager
7. In cell A1 enter the formula `=ColouredCell`

If cell B1 has a coloured background you should see its colour number otherwise it will show 0

Drag the cell formula down to the last row.

You can use the count if formula to count any cells grater than 0 `=COUNTIF(A:A,">0")`

[image: Named ranges and formulas to show adjacent cell colours]

**Important!**
Once the formula is added to the cell it will not update if the adjacent cell colour changes, the formula will have to be reapplied to the cell to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the wrong idea about conditional formatting: you want to base the data in your Excel sheet on the colour you have chosen, but conditional formatting does just the opposite: based on the values inside your cells you can choose a colour.